# ¿Como devolver un true o false al hacer una consulta en ASP Clásico?

Tags: asp

Quiero saber si la consulta devuelve alguna fila o no, estoy intentando hacerlo de esta manera:

```
rs2.ActiveConnection = MM_oConn_STRING
  query2 = "select *,  t1.cec as a from centrosacceso as t1 left join (SELECT Count(A.usuario) AS Total, B.cec FROM accesos A INNER JOIN emp B ON A.usuario = B.emp INNER JOIN cec C ON B.cec = C.cec INNER JOIN centrosacceso D ON C.cec = D.cec WHERE  D.activo = 1 AND D.estado = 'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO' AND A.fecha_acceso >= CONVERT(varchar , DATEADD(minute, -20,'" & nuevafecha & "'))  AND A.aplicacion is null GROUP  BY B.cec, C.cec_descri, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.estado, D.numpin, D.coorx, D.coory, D.activo) as t2 on t2.cec = t1.cec where t1.activo = 1 and t1.estado = 'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO';"
  rs2.CursorType = 3
  rs2.LockType = 1
  Call rs2.Open(query2)

  If Not rs2.EOF then
    response.write("verdadero")
  Else
    response.write("falso")
  end if
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado, es decir comprobando si la consulta tiene un dato, devuelve verdadero si no tiene nada devuelve falso, y siempre de devuelve verdadero encontrando o no datos en la consulta. ¿Cómo puedo resolver esto? ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tal parece que el tipo de cursor debe ser adOpenForwardOnly (0) para que al solicitar EOF responda adecuadamente cuando no hay registros y no permita moverse hacia atrás como el tipo 3.

De acuerdo a la documentación https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortype-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15